# LaTeX beamer: way to change the bullet indentation?

Tags: latex, beamer

I've checked the Beamer Class manual (PDF file).

I can't figure out how to change the indentation bullet assigns to \itemize.

[This is kind of important, as I'm using 2 column slides, and I don't want beamer to steal too much horizontal space].

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Beamer just delegates responsibility for managing layout of `itemize` environments back to the base LaTeX packages, so there's nothing funky you need to do in Beamer itself to alter the apperaance / layout of your lists.

Since Beamer redefines itemize, item, etc., the fully proper way to manipulate things like indentation is to redefine the Beamer templates.  I get the impression that you're not looking to go that far, but if that's not the case, let me know and I'll elaborate.

There are at least three ways of accomplishing your goal from within your document, without mussing about with Beamer templates.

### With `itemize`

In the following code snippet, you can change the value of `\itemindent` from `0em` to whatever you please, including negative values.  `0em` is the default item indentation.

The advantage of this method is that the list is styled normally.  The disadvantage is that Beamer's redefinition of `itemize` and `\item` means that the number of paramters that can be manipulated to change the list layout is limited.  It can be very hard to get the spacing right with multi-line items.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{0em}
  \item This is a normally-indented item.
\end{itemize}
```

### With `list`

In the following code snippet, the second parameter to `\list` is the bullet to use, and the third parameter is a list of layout parameters to change.  The `\leftmargin` parameter adjusts the indentation of the entire list item and all of its rows; `\itemindent` alters the indentation of subsequent lines.

The advantage of this method is that you have all of the flexibility of lists in non-Beamer LaTeX.  The disadvantage is that you have to setup the bullet style (and other visual elements) manually (or identify the right command for the template you're using).  Note that if you leave the second argument empty, no bullet will be displayed and you'll save some horizontal space.

```
\begin{list}{$\square$}{\leftmargin=1em \itemindent=0em}
  \item This item uses the margin and indentation provided above.
\end{list}
```

### Defining a `customlist` environment

The shortcomings of the `list` solution can be ameliorated by defining a new `customlist` environment that basically redefines the `itemize` environment from Beamer but also incorporates the `\leftmargin` and `\itemindent` (etc.) parameters.  Put the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{customlist}[2]{
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
      \advance\@itemdepth\@ne%
      \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth%
      \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
      \begin{list}
        {
            \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}
        }
        { \leftmargin=#1 \itemindent=#2
            \def\makelabel##1{%
              {%  
                  \hss\llap{{%
                    \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
              }%  
            }%  
        }
  \fi
}
{
  \end{list}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now, to use an itemized list with custom indentation, you can use the following environment.  The first argument is for `\leftmargin` and the second is for `\itemindent`.  The default values are 2.5em and 0em respectively.

```
\begin{customlist}{2.5em}{0em}
   \item Any normal item can go here.
\end{customlist}
```

A custom bullet style can be incorporated into the `customlist` solution using the standard Beamer mechanism of `\setbeamertemplate`. (See the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/change-bullet-style-formatting-in-beamer) question on the TeX Stack Exchange for more information.)

Alternatively, the bullet style can just be modified directly within the environment, by replacing `\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}` with whatever bullet style you'd like to use (e.g. `$\square$`).

Comment: From my understanding, the 2nd and the 3rd solution are the same, except that the 2nd solution allows you to set the style of the symbol used for an item. Can I somewhere in the 3rd solution define that symbol style? What I would like to do is create a custom list, define the symbol style for once, and then just operate with the other two parameters as suggested by you. Besides, upvoted this great answer.

Comment: @Talik3233: I've updated my answer with two methods of modifying the bullet style.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I upvoted this long ago & have been back to it several times over the years.  When nudging something by some number of units, you can use millimeters (mm) or points (pt); what kind of unit is em (i.e., `[0em]`)?

Comment: Am em is roughly the width of an uppercase M in the active font. See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lengths_in_LaTeX and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337 for more information.

Answer (score 22):

I use the package **enumitem**. You may then set such margins when you declare your lists (enumerate, description, itemize):

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0cm]
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
\end{itemize}
```

Naturally, the package provides lots of other nice customizations for lists (use 'label=' to change the bullet, use 'itemsep=' to change the spacing between items, [etc...](http://www.cam.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf))

Comment: Unfortunately beamer redefined itemize, so that when you use enumitem you lose the bullet symbols

Comment: enumitem would be ideal, but Beamer is too intrusive, so many of the settings fail to work.

Comment: As @DaveP said, unfortunately beamer is not compatible with enumitem

Answer (score 12):

Setting `\itemindent` for a new itemize environment solves the problem:

```
\newenvironment{beameritemize}
{ \begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1.5ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}   
  \addtolength{\itemindent}{-2em}  }
{ \end{itemize} }
```

Comment: This only decreases the indentation for the first line (at least in beamer). If an item contains more than one line of text, the following lines remain indented.

Answer (score 3):

To set the indentation globally, without using `enumitem` (which doesn't work on Beamer),
put the following in your preamble:

```
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{0.5cm}
```

`leftmargini` and `leftmarginii` change the first and second list level, respectively.

This solution was given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426581/itemize-within-itemize-and-reducing-indent-in-beamer/426588#426588).

Comment: This answer, and the reference, saved my life.

Answer (score -1):

Like Geoff's answer, I found a solution I like using **enumitem**. Set defaults with `\setlist[⟨names⟩,⟨levels⟩]{⟨keys/values⟩}` to inherit existing (theme?) attributes or `\setlist*[⟨names⟩,⟨levels⟩]{⟨keys/values⟩}` to fully reset. See the [enumitem documentation](https://github.com/jbezos/enumitem/blob/master/enumitem.pdf).

The following sets indentation for the first four levels of nested lists as well as explicitly declares labels. The labels here defaults to bullets for itemized lists and arabic numbers for enumerated lists. It then resets the default labels for nested lists; long-hyphen for 2nd itemized, single hyphen for third itemized, etc. The last line resets default label for 2nd level itemized enumerated lists to be alphabetic (a, b, c).

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=0em}
\setlist[2]{leftmargin=2em} %list within a list
\setlist[3]{leftmargin=2.5em} %list within a list within a list
\setlist[4]{leftmargin=3em}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\textbullet}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label={--}}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label={-}}
\setlist[itemize,4]{label={\textperiodcentered}}
\setlist[enumerate]{label={\arabic*}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label={\alph*}}
```

With enumitem you can also declare a specific label or spacing for a particular instance by adding the options e.g. `\begin{itemize}[label={*}]` This is Geoff's answer.

Comment: Don't use `enumitem` with beamer - that's a guarantee for trouble

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz why? You can reset the counter after slides I believe.

Comment: You loose all the carefully done configurations of beamer themes, like the bullets matching the inner themes, the colours, the font size configurations of nested lists, ... But more importantly, enumitem is simply not compatible with a lot of beamer's patches to the list environments. Try default overlay specifications like `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` and enjoy the train wreck