# How do you change the image of a bullet point in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

When I use the itemize environment, i.e.

```
\begin{itemize} 
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{itemize}
```

The bullet points are ugly bitmap graphics that have harsh (aliased) edges. I'd like it to be a nice, clean font character or vector graphic

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can simply set a symbol of your choice. Let me assume you'd like the `\checkmark` symbol, just write:

```
\begin{itemize} 
    \item[\checkmark] one
    \item[\checkmark] two
    \item[\checkmark] three
\end{itemize}
```

Furthermore, if it's too long to write, you can set a new command:

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\checkmark]}
```

and the whole thing becomes:

```
\begin{itemize} 
   \myitem one
   \myitem two
   \myitem three
\end{itemize}
```

Otherwise, you can use the `enumitem` package as stated in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822345/how-do-you-change-the-image-of-a-bullet-point-in-latex-beamer/2823479#2823479).

---

For document classes other than beamer, there are two more ways to do the trick:

In the preamble, write:

```
\def\labelitemi{\checkmark}
```

If you want to change the symbol in only one `itemize` environment, write:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\newcommand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
   \item one
   \item two
   \item three
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your "\myitem" solution and it works well. It looks a lot better. I also tried renewing the labelitemi command but I got an error that \labelitemi was not defined.

Comment: just edited to avoid the error you get. \renewcommand should be used inside the environment

Comment: Thanks again. I tried \def\labelitemi{\checkmark} in the preamble, but nothing changed when I used \item (still the default bitmap bullet). I then tried the \newcommand method inside the particular itemize and it did not change anything either. I tried \renewcommand inside the itemize environment and got an error because it was not defined. I also tried \def\labelitemi{\checkmark} in the preamble AND \renewcommand{\labelitemi} and got an error that it was undefined.

Comment: I found your solution again on a website while searching around on the web for "labelitemi". I wonder if the problem is that this is inside beamer. According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611276/latex-beamer-way-to-change-the-bullet-indentation beamer remaps the {itemize} environment...

Comment: Yes, it's true. the \newcommand and \def cause errors when using beamer (but not in other document classes). Now correcting the answer.

Answer (score 32):

Probably the best way is to use the beamer template:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\checkmark}
```

Comment: An alternative that may be of use for somebody: `\let\OldItem\item`
   `\renewcommand{\item}{\OldItem[\checkmark]}`

Answer (score 16):

So here is the long answer. I found this in the beamer manual. In beamer there are kind of two things you can do. One is to set the "innertheme".

```
\useinnertheme{circles}
```

This will have (roughly) the same effect as

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item[\textbullet]}
```

The other thing you can do is set the template

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\textbullet}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a nice image with graphicx:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\item[\includegraphics{./images/image.png}]{Text}
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot specify the size.

Answer (score 6):

If you `\usepackage{enumitem}` you can then then set the label as a parameter

```
\begin{itemize}[label=\checkmark]
   \item ....
   \item ...
\end{itemize}
```

[Full documentation is here.](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/)

Comment: Should be enumerate not itemize.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my trobules with Russian and custom beamber symbols using Asana-math:

```
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
```

which implies using XeLaTeX, but the idea is the same for LaTeX -- just set the symbols manually:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\blacktriangleright$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\QED$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\smblkcircle$}
```